# Creating, controlling, and destroying a Movie in Java

Tags: java, process, runtime, movie

I'm trying to make a piece of software that will start a movie (.m4v) in the default movie viewer, let the movie run and close it when required. I was thinking using `process` but after some messing around with it and some google searches, I've been unable to figure out how to implement such a thing. Here's what I have:

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = runTime
                .exec("A:\\test.m4v");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the error: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "A:\test.m4v": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`
What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to start this movie? What do I need to do as well to make the movie full screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `wmplayer.exe /play /close A:\\test.m4v` in your `.exec` method if you know the `.m4v` can be viewed on Windows Media Player. Or simply choose a different compatible player instead of Mplayer2.exe.

This `/close` command automatically closes the player once the video reaches the end.

e.g. The below code snippet opens the WMedia Player and plays the mp4 video in fullscreen mode.

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process process = runTime.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe /play /fullscreen C:\\56775-download.mp4");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: could you maybe put a bit of context code in there? i'm not sure what you mean :)

Comment: look at my edited answer. Let me know if you can play the file now.

Comment: Besides my missing codec's, I can. So, to make sure, to end the movie all i'd have to do is `process.destroy()` right?

Comment: `process.destroy()` is how you kill a process. Now, when and how you want to do it is a different question.

Comment: alright, that's all I need to know! thank you very much!